# add extra labels to x axis barplot

Tags: r, plot

Imagine that I have the following bar plot

```
counts <- table(mtcars$gear)
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution",
xlab="Number of Gears")
```

What I would like to do is to add extra categories, for example 2 and 6 gears. This would be, of course, reflected as 0 in the plot.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make it a factor and declare the levels:

```
counts <- table(factor(mtcars$gear,levels=2:6))
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution",
xlab="Number of Gears")
```

To add an explanation, factors are something meant for categorical variables. There's two aspect achieved by setting the levels as above. One you can detail what levels to expect, including missing. This is useful when say you subset and table etc. Second, you order the categories or factors. You can see it is plotted from 2 to 6. You can try doing this:

```
counts <- table(factor(mtcars$gear,levels=6:2))
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution",
xlab="Number of Gears")
```

The plot will reverse now. You can also see [this R chapter on factors](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html)

Comment: It worked perfect! Thanks!